# Make Mongo database availible online?

Tags: server, 16.04, database, mongodb

*Note: the server is on Azure and the client is running on my home computer*

I've installed Mongo and have it working on Ubuntu 16.04.

The client on my home computer currently has the following set for database and the application is working:

```
mongodb://localhost:27017/myData
```

I want to instead access:

```
mongodb://104.66.66.66:27017/myData
```

*(104.66.66.66 is the public IP of the Ubuntu Server)*

I'm running mongod on the Ubuntu server and I created a new security rule allowing incoming connections on 27017. Unfortunately the client still can't connect.

Anyone have instructions for making Mongo available to outside connections?

Comment: Is that a local or internet IP?

Comment: 104.66.66.66 would be the address I use to ssh into the server

Comment: Yes, but is it an external IP (your internet address) or a local IP (a LAN address)?

Comment: It's the public IP address

Comment: You need to setup port forwarding on your router.